# Selection range to HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

How can I transform a selected text range into a HTML element?

For example, string `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`, I've fetched the part `brown` that reflects selection points `start = 10` and `end = 14` (selection isn't built by user input).

Now, how do I transform this part of string into a `<span>brown</span>`?

P.S. I've looked into [How to wrap with HTML tags a cross-boundary DOM selection range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730967/how-to-wrap-with-html-tags-a-cross-boundary-dom-selection-range). The answer provided uses execCommand, but that doesn't satisfy me, because I need this to be as transparent as possible.

I'm using `Range` API for selections too, but as in this case- the "selection" is just stored pointers of `start/end` locations with no selection actually made.

I had an idea that I could use the pointers to create a selection in the background, wrap with `</span>` and that would be invisible to user, but then again... I have no idea how to execute this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in this case using methods of `Range`. I'm assuming your text is all contained in a single text node. For example:

```
<div id="test">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

First, create the range:

```
var range = document.createRange();
var textNode = document.getElementById("test").firstChild;
range.setStart(textNode, 10);
range.setEnd(textNode, 15);
```

To surround just the word "brown" within a span, you can use the range's `surroundContents()` method:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
range.surroundContents(span);
```

However, this won't work in some more complicated cases where the selection crosses node boundaries. Also, IE < 9 does not support `Range`, so you'd need a completely different solution for those browsers.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m3yJ5/

**Self-promotion section**

For more complicated cases, you could use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library and its [CSS class applier module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule), which surrounds any arbitrary selection or range in `<span>`s with a particular CSS class.

Comment: Already found out about `surroundContents` and used it, just couldn't provide my own answer yet. Thanks, accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` is wrapped in some element, say a DIV, for example:

```
<div id='myText'>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

You could write something like this:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('mytext');
var myText = ele.innerHTML;
var start = 10;
var end = 14;
var newText = myText.substring(0, start) + '<span>' + myText.substring(start, end) + '</span>' + myText.substring(end);
ele.innerHTML = newText;
```

JavaScript provides a number of string manipulation methods.  Try Googling `JavaScript String Methods`.