# Can I attach a class/id to a link that I programmatically insert using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am using the following code to insert a link to the currently selected text:

```
document.execCommand('CreateLink', false, 'link.com')
```

This works great, but I would really love to be able to insert a class/id with this link so as to make the styling of it easier with CSS. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class by assigning to the *className* property of a DOM element:

```
someElement.className = 'myClass';
```

Note that [`document.execCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an IE invention, it is not cross–browser. Instead use:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'link.com';
link.className = 'someClass';
link.id = 'someID';
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('link.com'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using this for a UIWebView in an iOS application, and it is convenient because it takes the text that is already selected and creates a link around that range. Is it possible to accomplish the same via your method mentioned above?

Comment: The method above only creates the A element and inserts it into the document, it dosen't replace anything. You can adapt the above to replace a range fairly easily, something like turn the range into a separate node (e.g. [Selection range to HTML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285960/selection-range-to-html-element)), then replace that node with the A using something like `rangeNode.parentNode.replaceChild(link, rangeNode);`.